# Is there a postgres function which can identify if the given value is in valid json syntax

Tags: postgresql

MySQL has json_valid(). I need to check if the given data is in valid JSON syntax in postgres.

I searched throughout the postgres documentation but had no luck in finding out the method. If ther is no built-in method, can yall tell what function can i use to create a new function for checking if the data is valid